# Pass a custom collection using WCF with NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

My windows applications are communicating using WCF with NetTcpBinding.Both applications are using a shared dll as proxy class.I need to pass a **custom collection** derived from the IList / CollectionBase / List from client to server. When i send a custom list through WCF, the recived list showing correct count but the properties in each item is null. Is it possible to pass custom collections through WCF with NetTcpBinding?

**Custom Collection Class**

```
[Serializable]
public class Message : CollectionBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public ArrayList OriginalCollection
{
    get { return InnerList; }
}

public Message this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return (Message)this.InnerList[index];
    }
    set
    {
        this.InnerList[index] = value;
    }
}

public Message AddValue(object value)
{
    Message data = null;
    try
    {
        data = new Message
        {
            Value = value.ToString()

        };
        this.InnerList.Add(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        data = null;
        throw ex;
    }
    return data;
    }
}
```

**Service Contract**

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "ITestMessageService")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Message))]
public interface ITestMessageService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(ReplyAction = "*")]
    void TestMessage(Message message);
}
```